# Generic DragDrop Behavior in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, attachedbehaviors

I made a Behavior [Drag Drop Beahvior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493450/drag-drop-row-behavior-on-wpf-datagrid/10493869#10493869) which take a Collection (Implementing IList like ObservableCollection,LIst)

And its working alrght...

but if I Use *CollectionViewSource.View* (in the Xaml Binding), the behavior falis....

How could I make this behavior Generic (LIke independent of type of DataSource attached to DataGrid)

Is it even possible as I am using methods for IList interface like

```
Insert(object item)
```

Comment: One purpose of a collection view is to sort a List.  So it is going to resist being sorted manually.  But that does not mean it cannot be done.  Just saying it might not be easy.   If you the collection view did sort which would you want to win?

Comment: yes u r right... filterng and sorting makes no sense in case of reordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem already has an open source solution, see [Wpf Drag & Drop behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39191/Wpf-Drag-Drop-behaviour). This behavior will implement drag drop for any ItemsControl, it should work for datagrid too.