# WPF Datagrid reorder rowitems

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I am new to both WPF and MVVM so please pardon if this is a silly question.

**Problem**: I am having a datagrid with two groups inside it say Male and Female. It is bound to Collectionviewsource which is an observable collection of persons. I have grouped based on Gender. If I drag a person in Male group to female group, I should be able to see dragged item in female group.

**Details**

Let's say I have a collection of Persons: Vinay, Vijay, Nandini, John, Sukanya etc.
These persons are grouped by genders: Male and Female.

**Goal**: Within a datagrid, I would like to drag a person from one group to another. I want to achieve this in MVVM way so that when I drag and move person ,property in viewmodel should change.

All I need are guidelines to follow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @vinay :)

The classic solution is to use a DragAndDrop behavior.
You have a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495448/generic-dragdrop-behavior-in-wpf-datagrid).
Follow the link in that thread in order to see the open source behavior.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, I'm compelled not to use any 3rd party DLLs in  my application. So above solution is not feasible for me.

Comment: You don't have to use any third party dll, there is source code there. Use it to create the proper behavior, then attach it to your xaml.

Comment: Good luck @vinay! If I have answered your question, please mark the answer as the correct one for others to see and use as well :)